# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

I run spark-submit:

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.graph.algorithms.TopicModeling TopicModel/target/TopicModel-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spark://172.16.6.109:7077 -tokens=/tmp/hadoop_fuse/spark/lda/corpus -dictionary=dictionary/part-00000 -ntopics=10 -niter=5`
```

but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
```

Comment: Please post more log

Comment: I have this error as well: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphKryoRegistrator`